# how to assign a string with multiple white spaces to a variable using awk

Tags: variables, awk, space, csh, preserve

I'm running into issues saving awk output to a variable and preserving the input. I have a tab-delimited file, ABC.txt, with the following format: Field 1 = A,
Field 2 = A  B <- 2 spaces between the letters A and B,
Field 3 = C.

```
set text = `awk -F "\t" '{print $2}' ABC.txt`

echo $text
A B <- 1 space between the letters A and B,

echo "$text"
A B <- 1 space between the letters A and B,
```

I need a solution where the variable preserves multiple spaces (I've seen instances where there can be two or three consecutive spaces):

echo $text = A  B <- 2 spaces between the letters A and B,

or

echo "$text" = A  B <- 2 spaces between the letters A and B,

Comment: what shell are you running this under?

Comment: Are you scripting in C shell?

Comment: @jared_mamrot The OP seems to be using csh, which doesn't have `$(...)`. The space compression is happening when the backticks are replaced.

Comment: I haven't been able to find a way to solve this with csh. Unlike Bourne-style shells, it doesn't seem to work to put the backtick expression inside double quotes. I get an empty result when I do that.

Comment: I don't think `awk` is relevant to this. You have the same problem with ```set text = `echo "A  B"` ```

Comment: Dont write scripts in CSH - https://www.google.com/search?q=csh+why+not

Comment: I agree with above. `csh` is the problem, don't use it. But upvote, as you've done a nice job of a [mcve]. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In CSH, for keeping the blanks you need to double-quote the variable-expansion **and** the backticks-expression; a simple case would be:

```bash
set text = "`echo 'A  B'`"
echo "$text"
```

```
A  B
```

But unlike POSIX compliant shells, CSH doesn't start a new quoting-context for the command-substitutions (aka. backticks-expressions); once you double-quote it, **the escaping rules becomes those of the surrounding double-quotes**:

1. no backslash escaping.
2. can't use a `"`.
3. `$` starts a variable-expansion.
4. `` ` `` starts a command-substitution.
5. etc...?

The way to include those characters as **literals** *inside* double-quotes is in fact to append them from *outside*: close the surrounding double-quotes, append the character (with backslash-escaping or inside single-quotes) and then reopen the double-quotes; the shell will take care of the concatenation for you.

Examples:

```bash
echo "..."\""..."
echo "..."\$"..."
echo "..."\`"..."
```

```bash
echo "..."'"'"..."
echo "..."'$'"..."
echo "..."'`'"..."
```

Both of those output:

```
..."...
...$...
...`...
```

---

What you need to do when double-quoting the command-substitution of `awk -F "\t" '{print $2}' ABC.txt` is then:

```bash
set text = "`awk -F "\""\t"\"" '{print "\$"2}' ABC.txt`"
echo "$text"
```

```
A  B
```

BTW, there's no point in using `awk -F "\t"`, it's easier with `awk -F '\t'` instead:

```bash
set text = "`awk -F '\t' '{print "\$"2}' ABC.txt
```

Comment: Wow, csh is painful.

Comment: Hi Fravadona, thanks for your help. I restated my initial problem. Please attempt to provide a response to the problem as it's currently stated. I am scripting in C shell.

Comment: @Devin I updated my answer but I have to say that the original one already showed how to handle `"` and `$` inside a **double-quotes backticks** expression.

Comment: "*I restated my problem*" ... Ah growing pains, but a virtual `--` on your previously perfect score on your [mcve]  (from me) (-;! Go forth and sin no more! Good luck.